# Java - Strings - counting sentences, words, etc

Tags: java, string

Here's a problem I'm facing when I try to break my string (which I took as an input).
IDK why it is taking this extra 'space' in the beginning of the arrayTry.

Why: `" H i ."`? Why not `"H i ."`

[image]

Please help me out.

2) Furthermore, how can i take paragraph as an input? 
How will the 'new line' be shown in the broken string array?
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use screen shots for code; place the code in the question as text.

Comment: We can not open this image.Please put your perticular code in question.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new here. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no extra space. That is just an empty String with a space behind it. Namely, the one you wrote in your loop:

```
System.out.println(arrayTry[i] + " ");
```

So, this means that `arrayTry[0]` is an empty String.

When you split on `""`, it will return an array of Strings, where there is one character per String, and apparently  an extra empty String in the beginning and at the end.

To split on newlines, just write it using the `\n` escape character for newline:

```
String[] paragraphs = input.split("\n+");
```

Comment: Ah! Got it. Thanks. 
What about Q2?

Comment: @SaifooKhan: I answered Q2 as well now.

Comment: How to take multiple line string input?
Now, once we have taken multiple line input, we break it. Right? 
My question here is, what value will be stored in the array about the 'new line' character?

Comment: By reading in a loop and append each new line to the String with a `\n` between it.

Comment: Maybe you should try to google this. This is been answer and asked about a million times. Roughly something like this: http://puu.sh/60fQ4.png

Answer (score 0):

Trim your string  (ie remove leading and trailing spaces) before splitting.

```
String strng = input.nextline();
strng = strng.trim();
strng.split(" ");
```

Comment: The trimming is pointless here. The extra empty String is caused by splitting on `""`. Check my answer.

Comment: @martinCourteaux Yes, I got that too.